# WPF listbox does not release the memory after value is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, telerik

I have a listbox that includes images, the value is bonded to a list but when I change the list the memory of the older value is not being released.

```c#
       public double ImageBorderWidth { get; set; }
    
            private BindableCollection<ThumbnailViewModel> _thumbnails;
            public BindableCollection<ThumbnailViewModel> Thumbnails
            {
                get => _thumbnails;
                private set
                {
                    _thumbnails = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Thumbnails);
                }
            }
```

And here is the XML file.

```xml
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="Thumbnails" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="0" Padding="5" AllowDrop="False" SelectionMode="Extended" telerik:ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior.SelectedItemsSource="{Binding SelectedThumbnails}">

                                    <telerik:RadListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <telerik:VirtualizingWrapPanel ItemHeight="{Binding ThumbnailHeight}" ItemWidth="{Binding ThumbnailWidth}" 
                                                                           CanVerticallyScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" ScrollStep="100"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </telerik:RadListBox.ItemsPanel>

                                    <telerik:RadListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadListBoxItemStyle}">
                                            <Setter Property="telerik:DragDropManager.AllowCapturedDrag" Value="True" />
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadListBoxItem}">
                                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </telerik:RadListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                                    <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
                                        <behaviors:NoRemovalListBoxDragDropBehavior AllowReorder="False" />
                                    </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>

                                    <telerik:RadListBox.DragVisualProvider>
                                        <telerik:ScreenshotDragVisualProvider  />
                                    </telerik:RadListBox.DragVisualProvider>
                                </telerik:RadListBox>
```

Comment: How did you determine this? There is no guarantee as to when managed memory will be released apart from program termination.

Comment: What Aluan said. In managed memory the Garbage Collector determines when and which objects will be released from memory. Even calling GC.Collect() will not guarantee you that objects viable for collection will actually be collected. You can eventually play with System.Runtime.GCSettings.LatencyMode.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the actual issue was due to automationpeer, after disabling it the issue went away.